# Latest News module equivalent for files in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I need a way to show just the last five added files, the same way the module Latest News can show the last five articles.

The files can be added in any way. For example, using the extension Phoca Download I can upload the files and set to then a category, but this extension can't show a list with a specified number of files of a category.

I'm using Joomla 1.6 and I couldn't find other file managers extensions to try.

Answer (score 1):

I seriously doubt there will be a module for this if the Phoca Download module doesn't do it. You're best bet is to modify the Phoca Download module to behave like you need it.